# Cannot override default Amplify withAuthenticator style with custom theme

Tags: react-native, aws-amplify

I am trying to customize the styling of the AWS WithAuthenticator HOC in my React Native application. I followed the Amplify [documentation](https://aws-amplify.github.io/docs/js/authentication#customize-ui-theme) step by step. However, the app keeps rendering the default styling (orange buttons) instead of the expected custom color.

```
import React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View } from 'react-native';
import Amplify from '@aws-amplify/core';
import config from './aws-exports';
import { withAuthenticator } from 'aws-amplify-react-native';
import { AmplifyTheme } from 'aws-amplify-react-native';

// custom colors for components 
const Mybutton = Object.assign({}, AmplifyTheme.button, { backgroundColor: '#000', });
//console.log('My own design: ', Mybutton)
const MyTheme = Object.assign({}, AmplifyTheme, { button: Mybutton });


class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Text>You are now signed in!</Text>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

export default withAuthenticator(App, { includeGreetings: true }, false, [], null, MyTheme)

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },
});
```

Can anyone point me to what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass the withAuthenticator call like this:

```
export default withAuthenticator(App, {includeGreetings: true, theme: MyTheme});
```

Then it will work.